# Why does Oracle give me a "Missing right parenthesis" error?

Tags: oracle, compiler-errors

I have something I have never seen before.  Here is a snippet of a SELECT statement:

```
FROM CustomerTable@pgr C
... (lots of stuff) ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRPC.OrderTable@pgr T1
  ON T1.CompanyID = C.CompanyID 
  AND COALESCE(T1.CustomerID, C.CustomerID) = C.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRPC.OrderTable@pgr T2
  ON T2.CompanyID = C.CompanyID 
  AND COALESCE(T2.CustomerID, C.CustomerID) = C.CustomerID
  AND T2.OrderDate > T1.OrderDate
EFT OUTER JOIN ... (more stuff)
```

The query gives me an error:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-02063: preceding line from PGR
00907.00000 - "missing right parenthesis"
```

Here's the really weird part: if I comment out the line `AND T2.OrderDate > T1.OrderDate` the error goes away.  I don't see how this would affect parentheses at all?

Another thing: if I run it on the PGR database directly, I don't get the error (but running it directly on the database is not an option for this part of the application).

I've read some other questions on this site regarding "*missing right parenthesis*", but they all seem to actually involve parentheses.  I'm totally lost on this one. (PS - I typed this in by hand instead of copy/paste, so if there are any spelling errors that's me, not the code)

Comment: As you say you typed the codesample by hand, could you provide a paste just to be sure there are no type errors?

Comment: Maybe it's the: `EFT OUTER JOIN`
that should be: `LEFT ...`?

Comment: can you paste the whole query? also can you tell us, what version of oracle is this, and for the db link, what is it linking to..oracle x.x or is this a HS link to sql server/mysql etc? is t1.OrderDate and t2.OrderDate a DATE?

Comment: Where are you running this from? Since you mention it's part of an application, if it's a built-up query string is it possible the construction isn't leaving a space between the line you comment out and the preceding one? It would be helpful to see the actual code you're running.